# Converting Yes and No to 0 and 1 in R

Tags: python, r, statistics

How do I convert a categorical value `(Yes/No)` to numeric value `(0/1)` in a data set of 20 variables and 3144 observations in R?

Answer (score 2):

In `R` we can either do

```
 df1[] <- +(df1=="Yes")
```

Or

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) as.integer(x=="Yes"))
```

NOTE: If "Yes" should be 0 and "No" is 1, replace `df1=="No"` and `x=="No"` in the post.

Answer (score 0):

"conversion" is easy, but im not sure how your data set looks like, if its a simple array with strings then this would help:

```
b = ["Yes", "No", "Yes"]
a = [ 0 if x.lower() == "yes" else 1 for x in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dat <- as.factor(c("yes", "no", "yes", "yes"))
as.numeric(dat) - 1
```